# Update in real time date difference in minutes for each row - PHP + MySQL query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm blocked on this and I would like some help. I have a MySQL table with this information:

```
start_session       | users  | points
---------------------------------------
2018-08-01 13:00:00 | anna   | 85.00
2018-08-01 11:23:00 | alfred | 35.00
2018-08-01 17:04:00 | georgy | 125.00
2018-08-01 19:30:00 | linda  | 42.00
2018-08-01 08:35:00 | alex   | 76.00
2018-08-01 10:29:00 | john   | 94.00
2018-08-01 15:27:00 | hugo   | 75.30
```

I want to get the difference in minutes between current date and start session date for each row showing in an HTML table, so I do this:

```
<table class="table">
<tr><td><b>Minutes</b></td><td><b>User - Points</b></td></tr>
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
 $res = mysql_query($sql);

 $date = date(Y-m-d H:i:s);

 if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res){
     $start_session = $row['start_session'];

          $start_date = new DateTime($start_session);
          $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($date));
          $minutes = $since_start->days * 24 * 60;
          $minutes += $since_start->h * 60;
          $minutes += $since_start->i;
?>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <?php echo $minutes." min"; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
          <?php echo $row['users']." - ".$row['points']." points"; ?>
      </td>
   </tr>
 <?php
     }
  }
 ?>         
</table>
```

It's working fine but time difference of minutes updates when I refresh the page and I want minutes updates automatically, I know that AJAX could be an option with SetInterval but I only want to update the minutes column, no rewrite all the table information. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please stop using PHP's ancient, insecure, and deprecated mysql_ API. I don't know about others, but I no longer answer questions that reference it.

Comment: I think AJAX is your only option unless you want the page to have to be refreshed

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I have already done, and this is how I did it.

In your markup, you need to store the original datetime, in your case, the start_session value, into an html element. I would store it as an attribute such as data-originaltime.

Using javascript and setInterval, you can frequently scan your markup for elements that have this attribute and re-compute the difference in time, then update the visible text in the page. That will do exactly what you want.

```
  <td data-originaltime="<?php echo $start_session; ?>">
      <?php echo $minutes." min"; ?>
  </td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trying to get value for each attrib and append it just for test but it doesn't work using id row as an indicator: `<td class="min_<?php echo $id;?>" data-originaltime="<?php echo $start_session; ?>" onload="cot('<?php echo $id; ?>')"><?php echo $minutes." min"; ?></td>` `function cot(idx){var title = $(".min_"+idx).attr("data-originaltime"); $(".min_"+idx).append(title);}` how can I scan it better?